# Recordar checkboxes anteriores y nuevos al editar con Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, formularios, checkbox

Holaa!
Escribo mi consulta para ver si alguien puede darme una mano, ya que estuve buscando en preguntas anteriores y no encontré solución a mi problema.
Cuando hago el formulario para editar un curso, tengo unos checkboxes para que se editen los días y horarios del mismo, el tema es que quiero que aparezcan seleccionados los que ya estaban seleccionados de antes y que también recuerde los nuevos ingresos. Había hecho lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero de esa manera, sólo me recuerda los que ya había seleccionado anteriormente y no los nuevos.
Y del código que tengo comentado me quedan seleccionados todos los checkboxes. ¿Cómo podría hacer para que me recuerde ambos?
Aclaro también, que armé dos tablas: una del curso y otra la tabla horarios que tiene: horario_id, curso_id, dia_id y hora_id.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y [haz el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. El código va como texto (y no como imagen) por [varias razones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/92278), por favor edita tu pregunta.

Comment: no uses imagenes para el codigo, ponlo en texto para poder usarlo si es necesario.